# Write to Firebase with serial number indexing

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

[image]

The data in LiveAutos is set using:

```
ref.child("hhh@hgh").child("latitude").setValue(location.latitude)
```

the data in Livelyautos is set using a python script by uploading a JSON file.

How can I write the data in LiveAutos similar to the LivelyAutos with serial numbers 0,1,2,3.
the database will be updated by multiple devices locations.

or how can I read the data from LiveAutos?

Comment: Sequential numeric/array indexes are a common anti-pattern in Firebase Realtime Database. I recommend checking out [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, storing sequential numeric elements is not a recommended way of adding data to Firebase Realtime Database, is rather an anti-pattern, since such a schema doesn't scale. What you can do is to use the push() method:

```
ref.child("hhh@hgh").push().child("latitude").setValue(location.latitude)
```

Which will produce a schema that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
 |
 --- hhh@hgh
      |
      --- $pushedId
             |
             --- latitude: 0.00
             |
             --- longitude: 0.00
```

In this way you can add as many locations as you want.